# Sort an List ~ Tkinter and Docker SDK Python 3.9

Tags: python, docker, tkinter

The Soloution :
Thanks to @DelriusEuphoria I could go on with my programm. The Soloution was to put the images into an list.

```
images = [image.tags for image in client.images.list()]; images.sort()
```

### Tkinter and Docker SDK Python 3.9

---

I want to make an Tkinter window where i can view all my installed docker images.
I already installed the [Docker-SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and wrote a simple script. It dont have any classes whatsoever because it should only be a prototype. My problem is that i dont´t get the list of the images sorted. It should be dynamic so if i install an new image it should just show up on the list. But I can not find a suitable solution. So when i start the Programm it is [looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoCUm.png) instead of being in a sorted list like this example I made in [plain text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5b5A.png). So can anybody help me that the images are sorted?

### The Code

```
# import tkinter and Docker
from tkinter import *
import docker

# docker Client instantiation
client = docker.from_env()

# new tkinter Window
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# Read all the installed docker images
image = client.images.list()

# Put the all the information about the images into a label
label = Label(frame, text=image)
label.pack()

# quit button
quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command=frame.quit)
quitButton.pack()

# window mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorted based on what

Comment: No, I am asking on what basis do you want to sort, like sort based on alphabetical order or date of creation, or so on...

Comment: Sorted in an list like in the plain text example. Like that it´s cut out only the part from '---'

Comment: I want it like alphabetical.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look into the Text widget or the wrap length option. I'm unsure at the moment if a formatted string is sufficient. What have you tried so far? I find plenty of examples in the web, including this site. Why didn't they solve your issue?

Comment: You might need something like: `images = [image.tags for image in client.images.list()]; images.sort()`. Just getting all the image tags and then sorting the list of tags

Comment: Thank you @DelriusEuphoria ^^ . Now i got a list and can grab the items out of the list and put it into the window.

Comment: if problem is solved then put solution as answer and later mark this answer as accepted - DON'T add word `solved` to title

Comment: Thx, new to Stackoverflow